# Printing a ref variable

Tags: c#, variables, reference

I'm tasked with printing the average and variance of a set of numbers in an array, and with this I needed to make a reference to avg which I have done. But I'm not understanding how I can now print what the avg is. I'm currently printing 0 when I run the program. This is my code:

```
    static double varianceValue(ref double avg, params double[] intValues)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double f = 0;
        double number = 0;
        double sv = 0;
        double variance= 0;

        foreach (int value in intValues)
        {
            sum += value;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.Length; i++)
        {
            number = intValues[i];
            avg = sum / intValues.Length;
            f = number - avg;
            sv += Math.Pow(f, 2);

        }
        variance = sv / (intValues.Length - 1);
        return variance;

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double avg = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("The avg of the variables in the array are: {0}", varianceValue(ref avg));
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe variance of 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 is: {0}", varianceValue(ref avg, 11.0, 13.0, 17.0, 19.0, 23.0));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Step through the program.

Comment: Seeming as you're assigning directly to `avg` (thus overwriting its value) there's no point making it a `ref` parameter, instead make it an `out` parameter or return a struct or tuple from the function.

Comment: Another good option would be a function that returns `Pair<double, double>`, both average and variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing zero at this point because the array is empty when you call

```
 Console.WriteLine("The avg of the variables in the array are: {0}", varianceValue(ref avg));
```

First call the variance function w/ array params (this will also set the avg). then call avg by itself.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double avg = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe variance of 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 is: {0}", varianceValue(ref avg, 11.0, 13.0, 17.0, 19.0, 23.0));
   Console.WriteLine("The avg of the variables in the array are: {0}", avg);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel positively stupid. Still very much new to this, order definitely matters. My apologies for a very dumb question. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: @jimjam456 if this helped, please make sure to accept the answer. =]

Comment: It definitely did, and I will as soon as I am able to. I'm confused as to why I'm getting negative reputation because of this question. I recognize it was a very simple answer, but still, I'm in the process of learning everything.

Comment: @jimjam456 make sure next time you have a question, state that you're a  "beginner" and new to the language -- it may help on some of the negative rep